# How can I find the newest screenshot image?

Tags: android, service, screenshot

I have been looking through related answers all around the web, but couldn't get rid of it. Under Android, i would like to make a service running in the background and only listening for screenshot event. When it occurs, than the service should find the screenshot image. I am stuck with this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You could listen to media Intent filters (listed below) and check if it is a new image in the Screenshot folder. 

com.android.camera.NEW_PICTURE, 
com.android.camera.NEW_VIDEO,
android.hardware.action.NEW_PICTURE,
android.hardware.action.NEW_VIDEO

Comment: There is no requirement for any "event" to be broadcast on a screenshot, or for the screenshot to be stored somewhere that your app can get to it. If you want to take screenshots, use the media projection APIs on Android 5.0+, and take the screenshots yourself, with user approval.